# How to properly install grib-api and jasper library to run flexpart model in ubuntu x64?

Tags: data-modeling

I'd like to install the FLEXPART program on my kubuntu 14.04 x64 LTS machine, they require the installation of the grib-api and jasper library first as mentionned in the website (http://flexpart.eu/wiki/FpInstall).
the issue is that i can't achieve correct installation of these two packages and therefore the proper install of FLEXPART. could someone give me the right way to install these two libraries in order to make the model run?

Comment: FLEXPART is a dispersion model that simulates transport and deposition of species including radionuclides in the environment. It's developed first by Pr. Andreas Stohl in 1995.

Answer (score 0):

there is a precompiled package of FLEXPART 9.02 for ubuntu distribution
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/utils/flexpart

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.